# Generic Repository, UnitOfWork and IOC container

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I am stuck to define a generic repository with AutoFac IOC container. I am keeping thing very simple and only showing relevant information.

**`BaseEntity`**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**`IRepository`**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    List<TEntity> GetAll();
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

**`IUnitOfWork`**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    int SaveChanges();
    void Dispose(bool disposing);
    IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;
}
```

**`IService`**

```
public interface IService
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
}
```

**`IService<TEntity>`**

```
public interface IService<TEntity> : IService where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    List<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

**`UnitOfWork`**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private readonly IEntitiesContext _context;
    private bool _disposed;
    private ObjectContext _objectContext;
    private Hashtable _repositories;
    private DbTransaction _transaction;


    public UnitOfWork(IEntitiesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
        {
            _repositories = new Hashtable();
        }
        var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        if (_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
        }
        var repositoryType = typeof(EntityRepository<>);
        _repositories.Add(type, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _context));
        return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
    }
}
```

**`Service<TEntity>`**

```
public class Service<TEntity> : IService<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }

    public Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return UnitOfWork.Repository<TEntity>().GetAll();
    }
}
```

**`EntityRepository<TEntity>`**

```
public class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IEntitiesContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> _dbEntitySet;

    public EntityRepository(IEntitiesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbEntitySet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbEntitySet.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now these are generic repository, services and unit-of-work. In my presentation I am using `IService<T>` which will be injected through AutoFac. Now I have 2 concerns:

1. I am directly using `EntityRepository` inside `UnitOfWork var repositoryType = typeof(EntityRepository<>)`, which is a problem for me because I am injecting dependencies through IOC.
2. If I need to use a custom Repository (by inheriting `EntityRepository`) in future, how can I inject it in my `UnitOfWork`?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would caution against using the generic repository + unit of work pattern that was super trendy a few years ago because it has problems not unlike the problems you're facing (along with problems stemming from the fact that EF crosses traditional DAL/Domain/BL boundaries). Simply put, I would not use repositories with EF unless absolutely necessary, and if I had to, I would not use the generic repository pattern.

If you're hell-bent on using this pattern, then you will need to understand the origins of the problem you're facing. Because you have a generic type being returned by your UnitOfWork "factory," you aren't able to instantiate it during your bootstrapping, you are being forced to to instantiate it on-demand at runtime, resolving using the type you're using in your `UnitOfWork` method call.

If you are okay with using the same repository instance for all of your resolutions, then just make your objects require `Repository<SomeType>` in your object constructors or properties with public setters, then use `RegisterGeneric()`. You can see how that is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226536/register-generic-type-with-autofac). This bypasses the entire "at runtime" requirement.

If you want to maintain the pattern of fetching a repository using a method, then you need to treat your `UnitOfWork` class as a factory and use [dynamic instantation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b).